# I can log onto my admin account but not personal

Tags: windows-7, login, login-screen

My pc froze up so I restarted it manually then I click on my personal account and it just shows the screen saying loading, I waited for like 30 minutes and was at the same screen then I have to manually turn it off again.

HELP! how do I get back my personal account?

Comment: did you just try logging in once or retried after the first time? sometimes it has randomly happened to me but trying again fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your registry might be corrupt, or there's an issue with network cached credentials.

What I would do is disable the network card (in the Administrator login) and see if that makes a difference when you log in as yourself again. Wait until it logs in this time, instead of shutting down.